# Problem motion capture Blender

Tags: animation, armature, motion-capture

I’ve a problem with Blender, I have to make a feet and animate it using a `.c3d` file with the motion capture of the movements.

But when I try to make the armature and assign the marker to the armature and I press the play, it’s like if the joint of the bones is not connected and they move free but they follow the markers and if I connect the joint and the bones not move.

Also I have tried to make an armature with the bones connected with the key <kbd>E</kbd> and they didn’t move. So I need to make a joint that let the bones follow the markers with an anatomical movement.

Could someone please tell me how I can find a solution for my problem?

My `.blend` file can be found here: [image]

[image: Bones at initial time]

[image: Bones moving free]

Comment: could you provide a .blend file to be able to have a look and help you?

Comment: Yes! Could you provide an email adress for sending it to you!! Thanks :D :D

Comment: You can upload it through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then send me the link

Comment: Ok! Perfect! This is the link :D [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2461" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2461/)

Comment: is the constraints you made in this file are correct? I can't figure out what is the structure of this c3d to be able to create a proper armature, could you explain or show what is the expected result you want?

Comment: Yes @Tak! The constraints that I made is copy location for each bone with his marker. The expected result is a foot doing dorsiflexion-plantarflexion movement (this: http://denverfitnessjournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/image003.gif). 
My .blend file is the right foot and the .c3d file there are 5 markers (1 in the heel, 1 in each side of the ankle, 1 in the first finger and 1 in the fifth finger), you could see here a scheme that I make: https://we.tl/IlzpmlsEPO

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've added an answer and uploaded an updated blend file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me you will only need to Bones, one connecting the ankle with the heel and another connecting the heel with the toes.

First you need to construct the armature properly:

- `Shift+A` add armature, then add a bone
- Select the two markers 01, 04 to position in between, and align 3D cursor with `Shift+S` then `Cursor to Selected`, this will position the bone between the two markers.
- Then enter edit-mode of armature and select the bone and `Shift+S` then `Selection to Cursor`
- Select the markers 05, and align 3D cursor with `Shift+S` then `Cursor to Selected`
- Then enter edit-mode of armature and select the second bone and `Shift+S` then `Selection to Cursor`

The second step is adding bone constraints:

- For the first (root) bone use two `Copy Location` constraint with second on 50% influence to get in between position of two markers 01 and 04. Then add `Damped Track` to track marker 05
- For the second bone use two `Damped Track` constraints with second on 50% influence to get in between position of two markers 02 and 03.

Result is shown as below:

[image]

The updated .blend file can be found here:

[image]

Comment: Maaany thaaanks!!!! :D

Comment: @Yaicobr Not a problem, glad I helped :) you can upvote the answer if it was helpful ;)